# Необходимо переходить на страницу с благодарностью после отправки формы PHP

Tags: php, html

После нажатия на кнопку на сайте - открывается сам файл .php и белый экран.
Редирект должен проходить на страницу itog.html, но он не происходит

```
<?php
    
      if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
        // Email на который будет отправлено письмо
        $to = "world.knitter.buissnes@gmail.com";
        // Email от имени которого будет отправлено письмо.
        // Введите email вашего сайта, либо, в крайнем случае,
        // продублируйте email из $to (может не работать)
        $from = "message.sendder@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Новая заявка на сайте"; // Тема присылаемого письма
        $message = "На сайте была заполнена форма покупки"."\r\n"
          // Если вы изменяли поля формы, внесите изменения ниже
          ."<b>Вариант доставки:</b> ".$_POST['theme-1']."\r\n"
          ."<b>Вариант оплаты:</b> ".$_POST['theme-2']."\r\n"
          ."<b>Имя:</b> ".$_POST['name']."\r\n"
          ."<b>email:</b> ".$_POST['email']."\r\n"
          ."<b>email:</b> ".$_POST['adress']."\r\n"
          ."<b>email:</b> ".$_POST['city']."\r\n"
          ."<b>email:</b> ".$_POST['district']."\r\n"
          ."<b>email:</b> ".$_POST['zip']."\r\n";
        $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header('Location: /itog.html');
        
      }
      
    ?>
```

Comment: А в логах пишет что-то вроде headers already sent)

Comment: @vp_arth А как посмотреть логи? в консоли висит следующее Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать только если клиенту еще не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п. Довольно часто возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми функциями, вроде include или require, в этом коде попадаются пробелы или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова header(). Те же проблемы могут возникать и при использовании PHP/HTML в одном файле. [Manual - PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)